# Android push notifications without FCM Backend

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

It seems to me that in the past, there was `GCM` (Google Cloud Messaging) which I understand as an endpoint one could send request to and if source and target are properly setup, a push notification is shown on target Android device.

Nowadays, `GCM` is deprecated and `FCM` (Firebase Cloud Messaging) is offered everywhere. It seems to me that FCM contains one more layer - `FCM Backend` (including logic to use Apple's `APNs` or web push).

Besides the contradicting information that `FCM` *"delivers messages at no cost"* and *"firebase pricing plan"* page where *"no cost"* means only *"up to some limits"*, I would be interested:

**Is there any possibility to send the push notification "the old way"** (similarly to APNs) by just utilizing the `Android Transport Layer` (as specified on the [FCM Architectural Overview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/fcm-architecture)) at no cost with no limits (thus not using the `FCM Backend` with the added value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cost to calling FCM to send messages, and the only usage limits are to protect misuse of the service from affecting other users.

---

I don't think there ever was a way to send device-to-device messages through GCM, but definitely hasn't existed in FCM since its introduction in 2016.

You can [send messages from a trusted environment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) which then delivers them to the targeted devices, and you can (**much** less common) [send messages from a device](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream) to FCM and [from there to your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/receive-upstream).

Sending messages needs **to** devices needs to happen from a trusted environment, to prevent a malicious user from being able to send whatever message they want to all of your users.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the pricing plan. When I look properly, there is still "no cost" for the `Cloud Messaging (FCM)` line. In that case, it does not make any sense to try to avoid the backend.